# Remove tabs or spaces from empty lines

Tags: phpstorm

I know PhpStorm allows the option to remove spaces at the end of a line.

Is it possible to configure it to remove tabs or spaces on empty lines?

Example: I type the following

```
if (1 == 1) {
```

Then I press enter twice, and I continue coding...

```
if (1 == 1) {

    savePlanet();
```

The empty line in the middle now has spaces, but I want just an empty line.

Comment: 1) Please show your current settings for the appropriate options 2) Please show an example of such code (screenshot with clearly visible whitespace  might do; otherwise -- share some simple file that can be downloaded and state the lines where IDE does not remove them) .. because as far as I'm aware it does remove them for me.

Comment: Hi @LazyOne, I'm using a clean install of PHP Storm (so the default config applies)

Comment: Added some sample code.

Comment: Well ... spaces get removed on Save not on typing. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/general.html?search=trailing -- `Strip trailing spaces on Save`

Answer (score 9):

You have 2 options here:

1. `Settings | Editor | General`, `Strip trailing spaces on Save` -
   when it's set to `All`, all trailing spaces/tabs are removed on
   Save, including the ones on empty lines
2. `Settings | Editor | Code
   Style | <Your language> | Tabs and Indents`, `Keep indents on empty
   lines`: when disabled, spaces/tabs on empty lines are removed on
   code reformatting

Comment: The actions from "2." helped! Thanks! :)